# How to create session variable and retrieve in JavaScript MVC3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to create a variable Session in JavaScript and Retrieve it in same JavaScript

My Code

```
  '<%Session["Test"] = "Welcome DS";%>';
        var session_value = '<%=Session["Test"]%>';
        alert(session_value);
```

its giving "<%=Session["Test"]%>" alert result, Its not giving Session values

Comment: I added the razor tag to your question, since the current question suggests that you are using a different view engine.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong syntax that is for another version of razor. You can change it to:

```
alert('@Session["Test"]');
```

Notice the use of the `@` sign. You can [refer to this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3razor.aspx) for the proper syntax.

Comment: You don't have to use the razor engine. You can still use the traditional asp.net syntax.

Comment: If I can try it now, I will. The OP tagged his question as MVC 3 so I assume the project is in MVC 3 and that syntax won't work. The `<%= =%>` will no longer work.

Comment: again.. you don't have to use the Razor engine. On project creation you have the option to use the old view engine (default options are 'Razor' or 'ASPX'), in which case this will work perfectly. (This is still the case in MVC4)

Comment: We could have both asked the OP first then what engine he uses. I think I did mention that he is probably using a wrong razor engine.

Comment: When creating new project you can choose `ViewEngine`, even MVC 4 has old engine support.

Comment: "You are using a wrong syntax" ... that is not per sé correct.
However, in the case OP is using Razor without knowing it, your answer might be relevant. That is also the reason why I don't downvote it, it might still be a usefull answer.

Comment: Yes point taken to both of you @webdeveloper and Yoeri. That's not what I meant. I am under the assumption that the OP uses the razor engine that uses `@`. That is  by default I believe, at least that's what I uses all the time.

Comment: @Yoeri, yes thank you, the same reason I did not downvote yours because **I know** that's valid too. Also, downvoting for me, is only for **misleading** or **incorrect** information that will never EVER work.

Comment: You'd be surprised how many people still use the old familiar syntax.

Comment: I know, yeah, well how about how many people still uses webforms.

Comment: @Yoeri  I am using MVC3 with Razor View Engine

Comment: alert('@Session["Test"]'); Its giving Blank Value

Comment: You sure you have a value in your session item?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET thinks what you write is a plain string.
Removing the quotation marks should do the trick if we're talking about an .aspx file.

```
<%Session["Test"] = "Welcome DS";%>

var session_value = <%=Session["Test"]%>;
```

Comment: Without quotation marks its not working, its showing, warning near <%

Comment: could you verify that you are using the correct view engine?
What is the extension of the file you are writing in?

Comment: The extension of file is .cshtml

Comment: Then you have, indeed, been writing the wrong syntax from the start.

Comment: either way you choose to change your project to the ASPX view engine, or you start reading this: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you really need your session variable only in Javascript why donøt you use a client side Session variable?

for example the html5 [sessionStorage](https://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/)

You can set it like this:

```
sessionStorage.myVariable = "myvalue";
```

and read it like this:

```
var x = sessionStorage.myVariable
```