# How to Create Session Variable in JavaScript MVC3 Razor View engine .cshtml

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am  using MVC3 with Razor View engine,

i have .cshtml page in that i have a JavaScript function, inside that JavaScript function, i want to create Session variable and retrieve that session in same JavaScript function.

how to achieve this..

Comment: Did you try to do so? and i think sessions are server variables.

Comment: I think you are [asking the same questions here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031917/how-to-create-session-variable-and-retrieve-in-javascript-mvc3/16032109#16032109). Besides why would you want to create a session item in `js`? Remember that js runs on the client. So do you intend to do another http call and set a session item?

Comment: @vonv. My previous code to creating a Session variable in JavaScript was wrong thats why i asked separated question for that..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Description

The Session is on the server side so you need to call the server in order to set or retrieve session variables.

Just post to a controller and set the Session variable there.

### Sample

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $.post('/SetSession/SetVariable', 
           { key : "TestKey", value : 'Test' }, function (data) 
    {
        alert("Success " + data.success);
    });
});
```

**Mvc Controller**

```
public class SetSessionController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SetVariable(string key, string value)
    {
        Session[key] = value;

        return this.Json(new { success = true });
    }
}
```

### More Information

- [Save and retrieve Session data via Ajax using JQuery in an MVC 3 application](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Save-and-retrieve-Session-data-via-Ajax-using-JQuery-in-an-MVC-3-application.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

To add a session with the javascript code. just must be to add this code

```
sessionStorage.setItem("MyId", 123);
```

and you can use this code to call the added session

```
var value = sessionStorage.getItem("MyId");
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: thanks for getting my attention, I hope the description you added helped.