# How to Modify Session Variable in JavaScript MVC4 Razor View engine .vbhtml

Tags: javascript, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, session, razor

I've used this info but its not working

[How to Create Session Variable in JavaScript MVC3 Razor View engine .cshtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037538/how-to-create-session-variable-in-javascript-mvc3-razor-view-engine-cshtml)

Any idea?

This is my SetVariable ActionResult:

```
Public Function SetVariable(key As String, value As String) As ActionResult
    Session(key) = value
    Return Me.Json(New With { _
        Key .success = True _
    })
End Function
```

This is the JS function which calls the previous function

```js
function Comprobacion2(s, e) {
        
        $(function () {
            $.post('/Home/SetVariable',
                   { key: "cadena", value: "Nueva" }, function (data) {
                       alert("Exito, cambio realizado " + '@Session("cadena")');
                   });
        });

    }
```

Comment: Does the function gets called? If it does, I'm pretty sure the Session variable is getting modified.

Comment: Yes, this js function call the SetVariable function

(Edited original post)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue using another function:

```js
function Comprobacion3(s, e) {
        $(function () {
            $.get('/Home/GetVariable',
                   { key: "cadena" }, function (data) {
                       alert(data);
                   });
        });
    }
```